# Video - How to open .a Video format?

Tags: video, youtube, file-extension

I downloaded several files from Video-Sharing websites (Like YouTube and others) with IDM which is downloaded Completely. But the Extension of these videos are `.a`.
I Changed extension to `.webm`, then i could hear just the Sound of the Video (I Used Google-Chrome Browser to open my new .webm file).
Is there any way to open `.a` extension Video files?

Comment: @OP are you sure it is a valid video? Look here: http://www.fileinfo.com/filetypes/video no .a reported

Comment: @vfbsilva : I Think i'm sure! Because i downloaded the link which IDM Could not download that. i can only hear to my video sound.

Comment: `.a` is evidently audio in a `.webm` container.

Comment: Try Videolan.org   Get VLC it plays almost anything.

Comment: I Tried Webm but i can only have SOUND not VIDEO. also i tried VLC But Nothings !

Comment: try to change the extension to `.avi` or `.mp4`, maybe the video is not in webm format but has a compatible audio codec

Comment: @Joserobertoaraujojunior: I just tried that, Not solved.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `file` command in Linux or Cygwin to identify the file format regardless of it extension, then you can find a program that can open that format.